# Is this proof for Bézout's Lemma correct? How would the converse be proven?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would appreciate if someone could tell me whether my proof for Bézout's identity is correct. I'm also asked to prove $\exists k,l\in \mathbb Z:ak+lb=1\implies gcd(a,b)=1$. Is the same  true for other numbers other than 1? Here's my proof:

---

If if $d$ is the greatest common factor of two non-zero integers $a$ and $b$, then $\exists x,y\in\mathbb Z:ax+by=d$

> *Proof* $\ $ Let $S=\{ak+bl\gt0|k,l\in\mathbb Z\}$. First we want to show $S\not=\emptyset$. \begin{align}(a\gt0)&\ |a|=(1)a+(0)b \\ (a\lt0)&\ |a|=(-1)a+(0)b\\ (b\gt0)&\ |b|=(0)a+(1)b \\ (b\lt0)&\ |b|=(0)a+(-1)b.\end{align} So $S$ is not empty and, by the WOP, it contains a least element, say c.
>
> Next we would like to show $c|a$. Assume (for the sake of contradiction) that $c$ does not divide $a$. Then by the division algorithm, $$a=cq+r, \text{for some }q,r\in \mathbb Z\ \text{with }0\le r\lt c.$$
>   Since $c=ak_{0}+bl_{0}$ for some $k_{0},l_{0}\in\mathbb Z$, then \begin{align} a=cq+r\Longleftrightarrow r&=a-cq\\ &=a-(ak_{0}+bl_{0})q\\ & =a(1-k_{0}q)+(-ql_{0})b,\ \text{so }r\in S.\end{align} However, since $r<c$ and $c=min\ S$, it must follow that $r=0$ and, thus, $c|a$. Similarly, $c|b$.
>
> Next we must show that for some integer $d$,$\ $ $d|a \land d|b \implies d|c$. Suppose $d|a \land d|b$. Then $\exists m,n\in\mathbb Z(a=dm \land b=dn).$ Substituting, \begin{align} c&=ak_{0}+bl_{0}\\ &=(dm)k_{0}+(dn)l_{0}\\ &=d(mk_{0}+nl_{0}),\text{ as desired.}\end{align} QED
>
> ---

Comment: Looks like one of the standard proofs, to me. For $c\ne1$ it is of course nonsense that $ak+lb=c$ implies $c=\gcd(a,b)$, as practically any numerical experiment will tell you.

Comment: Couldn't you multiply both sides of the equality by any integer?

Comment: Of course you can. Your point?

Comment: Omg lol nevermind... thank you.

Comment: To prove that $(\exists k,l\in \Bbb Z \;(ak+bl=1)) \implies \gcd (a,b)=1$ it suffices that if $n=\gcd(a,b)$ then $a=a'n$ and $b=b'n$ with $a',b'\in \Bbb Z $  so  $n(a'k+b'l)=ak+bl=1$  so $n$ divides $1$ so $1=n=\gcd (a,b).$